# Xamarin.Android AAPT.exe Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Currently , I had install Xamarin in Visual Studio, when I compile the source code,
the error showing as below image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seems that you have not SDK, NDK and Java SE developement tools on your system.
Download this tools then set the path in Tools > Options > Xamarin

[Xamarin Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGeNZ.png)